# passing URL in XMLHttpRequest.open()

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest

when I am passing the hard coded URL its working fine, but when creating the url using its parameters, its not working

```
var server = "localhost";
  var port = "8080";
  var db = "US";
  var lon = "-77.092609";
  var lat = "38.871256";
  var epsg = "epsg:4326";
  var inp= "5";

  var url = '"http://'+server+':'+port+'/rest/'+db+'.json?q=travel&point='+lon+','+lat+','+epsg+'&inp='+inp+'"'; 
  document.write(url);
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/rest/US.json?q=travel&point=-77.092609,38.871256,epsg:4326&inp=5",true);//WORKS FINE
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);//DOES NOT WORK!!
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the double quotes at the start and end of your string.

```
var url = 'http://'+server+':'+port+'/rest/'+db+'.json?q=travel&point='+lon+','+lat+','+epsg+'&inp='+inp;
```